# Higher lower game

Tags: python, beginner, number-guessing-game

I'm currently learning python with an udemy course. I wrote this code, which is meant to be a higher lower game, where the second answer always stays. As far as i tested it my code is working fine, but i feel like many solutions are bad. Its just felt weird coding some of the solutions, but i cant come up with better stuff. I would really aprecciate if someone would oversee my code and give some example for bad writing of myself with a better solution.

Heres my code:

```
from art import logo, vs
import random 
from game_data import data
from replit import clear

def game():
  score = 0
  print(logo)
  lost = False
  options = ["spaceholder", random.choice(data)]
  options = print_options(options[1])
  while not lost:
    return_values = compare(options[0], options[1], score)
    score = return_values[1]
    lost = return_values[0]
    if not lost:
      options = print_options(options[1])


# print both persons
def print_options(a):
  char1 = a
  new_list = data
  new_list.remove(char1)
  char2 = random.choice(data)
  new_list.append(char1)
  print(f"Compare A: {char1['name']}, a {char1['description']}, from {char1['country']} ")
  print(vs)
  print (f"Against B: {char2['name']}, a {char2['description']}, from {char2['country']} ")
  return char1, char2


# get input and compare both persons
def compare(adict, bdict, score):
  guess=input("""Who has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B': """)
  a = adict["follower_count"]
  b = bdict["follower_count"]
  if guess == "A" and a > b:
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Youre right! Current score: {score + 1}")
    return False, score +1
  elif guess == "B" and b > a:
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Youre right! Current score: {score + 1}")
    return False, score + 1
  else:
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Sorry, thats wrong. Final score: {score}")
    return True, score



game()
```

Edit:
imports:
clear is just clearing the console
art:

```
logo = """
    __  ___       __             
   / / / (_)___ _/ /_  ___  _____
  / /_/ / / __ `/ __ \/ _ \/ ___/
 / __  / / /_/ / / / /  __/ /    
/_/ ///_/\__, /_/ /_/\___/_/     
   / /  /____/_      _____  _____
  / /   / __ \ | /| / / _ \/ ___/
 / /___/ /_/ / |/ |/ /  __/ /    
/_____/\____/|__/|__/\___/_/     
"""

vs = """
 _    __    
| |  / /____
| | / / ___/
| |/ (__  ) 
|___/____(_)
"""
```

game data:

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ariana Grande',
        'follower_count': 183,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dwayne Johnson',
        'follower_count': 181,
        'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Selena Gomez',
        'follower_count': 174,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kylie Jenner',
        'follower_count': 172,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman and Self-Made Billionaire',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kim Kardashian',
        'follower_count': 167,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Lionel Messi',
        'follower_count': 149,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Argentina'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Beyoncé',
        'follower_count': 145,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Neymar',
        'follower_count': 138,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Brasil'
    },
    {
        'name': 'National Geographic',
        'follower_count': 135,
        'description': 'Magazine',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Justin Bieber',
        'follower_count': 133,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Canada'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Taylor Swift',
        'follower_count': 131,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kendall Jenner',
        'follower_count': 127,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and Model',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Jennifer Lopez',
        'follower_count': 119,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Nicki Minaj',
        'follower_count': 113,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Trinidad and Tobago'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Nike',
        'follower_count': 109,
        'description': 'Sportswear multinational',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Khloé Kardashian',
        'follower_count': 108,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality and businesswoman',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Miley Cyrus',
        'follower_count': 107,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Katy Perry',
        'follower_count': 94,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kourtney Kardashian',
        'follower_count': 90,
        'description': 'Reality TV personality',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Kevin Hart',
        'follower_count': 89,
        'description': 'Comedian and actor',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ellen DeGeneres',
        'follower_count': 87,
        'description': 'Comedian',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Real Madrid CF',
        'follower_count': 86,
        'description': 'Football club',
        'country': 'Spain'
    },
    {
        'name': 'FC Barcelona',
        'follower_count': 85,
        'description': 'Football club',
        'country': 'Spain'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Rihanna',
        'follower_count': 81,
        'description': 'Musician and businesswoman',
        'country': 'Barbados'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Demi Lovato',
        'follower_count': 80,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': "Victoria's Secret",
        'follower_count': 69,
        'description': 'Lingerie brand',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Zendaya',
        'follower_count': 68,
        'description': 'Actress and musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Shakira',
        'follower_count': 66,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Colombia'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Drake',
        'follower_count': 65,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Canada'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Chris Brown',
        'follower_count': 64,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'LeBron James',
        'follower_count': 63,
        'description': 'Basketball player',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Vin Diesel',
        'follower_count': 62,
        'description': 'Actor',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cardi B',
        'follower_count': 67,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'David Beckham',
        'follower_count': 82,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'United Kingdom'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Billie Eilish',
        'follower_count': 61,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Justin Timberlake',
        'follower_count': 59,
        'description': 'Musician and actor',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'UEFA Champions League',
        'follower_count': 58,
        'description': 'Club football competition',
        'country': 'Europe'
    },
    {
        'name': 'NASA',
        'follower_count': 56,
        'description': 'Space agency',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Emma Watson',
        'follower_count': 56,
        'description': 'Actress',
        'country': 'United Kingdom'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Shawn Mendes',
        'follower_count': 57,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Canada'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Virat Kohli',
        'follower_count': 55,
        'description': 'Cricketer',
        'country': 'India'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Gigi Hadid',
        'follower_count': 54,
        'description': 'Model',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Priyanka Chopra Jonas',
        'follower_count': 53,
        'description': 'Actress and musician',
        'country': 'India'
    },
    {
        'name': '9GAG',
        'follower_count': 52,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'China'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ronaldinho',
        'follower_count': 51,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Brasil'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Maluma',
        'follower_count': 50,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Colombia'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Camila Cabello',
        'follower_count': 49,
        'description': 'Musician',
        'country': 'Cuba'
    },
    {
        'name': 'NBA',
        'follower_count': 47,
        'description': 'Club Basketball Competition',
        'country': 'United States'
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you tell us about the imports, or better yet, show us that code too?

Comment: @200_success I added it. I hope thats what you meant  
And thanks for welcoming me here. Im very new to python btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to go too heavily into refactoring the whole thing.

Some basic readability things:

```
return_values = compare(options[0], options[1], score)
score = return_values[1]
lost = return_values[0]
```

It would be much clearer if you did:

```
lost, score = compare(options[0], options[1], score)
```

You have indented things with two spaces, which is odd,  normally we use 4 spaces for indenting each level!

In terms of best practice:

`print_options` does a couple of things,  both selecting another contestant AND printing them out.  each function should only do one thing e.g.:

```
options = print_options(options[1])
```

could be: (I made some notes too..)

```
def get_options(char1): #a->char1
  #char1 = a #removed
  new_list = data
  new_list.remove(char1)
  char2 = random.choice(data) # Should be random.choice(new_list)?
  #new_list.append(char1) #This does nothing? 
  return char1, char2

def print_options(options):

    print(f"Compare A: {char1['name']}, a {char1['description']}, from {char1['country']} ")
    print(vs)
    print (f"Against B: {char2['name']}, a {char2['description']}, from {char2['country']} "

[...]     
    options = get_options(options[1])
    print_options(options)
```

The following is the same code copied and pasted,  this is a good clue you could refactor it.

```
if guess == "A" and a > b:
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Youre right! Current score: {score + 1}")
    return False, score +1
elif guess == "B" and b > a:
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Youre right! Current score: {score + 1}")
    return False, score + 1
```

something along the lines of

```
if a>b and guess == "A" or a<b and guess == "B":
    clear()
    print(logo)
    print(f"Youre right! Current score: {score + 1}")
    return False, score + 1
```

Also,  `compare` does at least three different things too (Get input, compare, and print) It might be good to split this into two or three functions (`get_guess()` `check_guess(options, guess)` and `print_result(lost,score)` might be a good idea.

Comment: Pssst, to make your answer _even_ better (It is already great!), maybe mention something about the formatting of the code? 2 indents is really uncommon! ^^

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, I wondered why I ended up with 6 spaces in mine...

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

Great tips from the other answer, here are just some more bits and bobs.

#### Use the library capabilities to their fullest

```
  char1 = a
  new_list = data
  new_list.remove(char1)
  char2 = random.choice(data)
  new_list.append(char1)
```

This, in addition to the uncommon indentation sticks out to me. Why are we removing, why are we adding, why are we redefining? Consider

```
char1, char2 = random.sample(data, 2)
```

#### Excplicit over implisitt

Try to make your code as clear as possible. We are not collecting data, we are collecting *twitter data*. Similarly we are not returning *char1* and *char2* but we are returning *celebrities* (or really *accounts*, but too lazy to change my code now)

```
def compare(adict, bdict, score):
  guess=input("""Who has more followers? Type 'A' or 'B': """)
  a = adict["follower_count"]
  b = bdict["follower_count"]
```

This also seems strange, why not just make `compare` take in `a` and `b`. Remember the thing about explicit? Yeah, those should probably not be called `adict` and `bdict`.

#### Tricks

What would you do if you needed to compare 3 or 4 twitter accounts? You would quickly run into issues. The quick and dirty solution is as follows:

We sort the accounts in decending order of number of followers

```
twitter_account_0, twitter_account_1
```

Then we label them with letters

```
twitter_account_0, twitter_account_1
        A                 B
```

The trick now is that we shuffle the *labels* instead of the actual accounts

```
twitter_account_0, twitter_account_1
        B                 A
```

So `twitter_account_0` is really the biggest one. But we print them by label so it looks like

```
A, twitter_account_1
B, twitter_account_0
```

So when you type B, we just need to check that this corresponds to the account with index 0. Slightly quicker to do this with a lookup table. One *very* rough implementation looks like the following

```
import string

from art import logo, vs
import random
from game_data import twitter_data

TOTAL_CELEBRITIES = 3


def celebrity_info(celebrities_by_label, info):
    for label, celebrity in celebrities_by_label.items():
        print(label, end=", ")
        for key in info[:-1]:
            print(celebrity[key], end=", ")
        print(celebrity[info[-1]], end="\n\n")


def get_celebritites(twitter, total=TOTAL_CELEBRITIES, sort_key="follower_count"):

    indexes = random.sample(range(0, total), total)
    index_2_label = [string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in indexes]
    label_2_index = {label: index for index, label in enumerate(index_2_label)}

    labels = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:TOTAL_CELEBRITIES])

    celebrities = random.sample(twitter, total)
    celebrities.sort(key=lambda d: d[sort_key], reverse=True)
    celebrities_by_label = {
        label: celebrities[label_2_index[label]] for label in labels
    }
    return (
        celebrities_by_label,
        label_2_index,
        labels,
    )


# get input and compare both persons
def round(celebrities_by_label, label_2_index, labels):
    celebrity_info(celebrities_by_label, ["name", "description"])

    answer = input(f"Who has more followers? Type one of {labels}: ").upper()
    # The celebrity with index 0 always has the highest count
    return label_2_index.get(answer, None) == 0


def game():
    print(logo)
    celebrities_by_label, label_2_index, labels = get_celebritites(
        twitter_data, TOTAL_CELEBRITIES
    )

    points = 0
    while round(celebrities_by_label, label_2_index, labels):
        points += 1
        print(f"Youre right! Current score: {points}")
        celebrities_by_label, label_2_index, labels = get_celebritites(
            twitter_data, TOTAL_CELEBRITIES
        )
    print(f"Sorry, thats wrong. Final score: {points}\n")

    celebrity_info(celebrities_by_label, ["name", "description", "follower_count"])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    game()
```

#### The proper way

The proper way is to make a `class` that is a `datastructure` and let each twitter account be an instance of this class. I will leave it to you to give this a chance. It is a great opportunity to get introduced to object oriented programming!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!
It helped a lot and i am going to look into OOP today.